# Excel 2016: VBA code in one workbookwill affect cells in other workbooks

Tags: vba, excel-2016

I've used the same code in Excel 2013 and Excel 2010, it works perfectly fine, but when the system upgraded to Excel 2016, things changed, code works in one book will be implemented in other workbook if I type words in that workbook, any idea? thanks a lot
here is the part of the code

```

```
Sub createsheets()
On Error Resume Next
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each ws In Workbooks("Book2").Worksheets
If ws.Name <> "test" Then ws.Delete
Next
For j = 4 To 10

PauseTime = 5
starter = Timer
Do While (Timer < starter + PauseTime)
Application.StatusBar = "do nothing..."
DoEvents
Loop
Application.StatusBar = ""
Workbooks("Book2").Worksheets.Add.Name = "name" & j - 3
current_worksheet_name = "name" & j - 3
Workbooks("Book2").Worksheets(current_worksheet_name).Cells(1, 1) = "this is a test"
Next
End Sub
```

```

***for this code, if i type words in another workbook, say the workbook name is "ABC", new sheets with name "namej" will be created in my current workbook"ABC".
which is apparently unacceptable, I think i've specified the workbook , but it still doesn't work

Comment: have you tried setting the workbook to ThisWorkbook?

Comment: won't work either, VBA still running across both workbook,thanks @mo.h

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this...

```
Sub createsheets()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set wb = Workbooks("Book2.xlsx")
If Not wb Is Nothing Then

On Error Resume Next
For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
    If LCase(ws.Name) <> "test" Then ws.Delete
Next

For j = 1 To 7
    wb.Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "name" & j
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    sh.Cells(1, 1) = "this is a test"
Next
Else
    MsgBox "Book2.xlsx is not opened.", vbExclamation
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, @sktneer , thanks for your reply, but it seems the above code still can't avoid the problem i described above, to be more specific, if  I use the code above add ```PauseTime = 5
starter = Timer
Do While (Timer < starter + PauseTime)
Application.StatusBar = "do nothing..."
DoEvents
Loop``` in between, when I type words in another workbook, sheets will be created in the new workbook, so frustrated for this problem